# Mechanism behind capillary action

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action

When we place a capillary tube in a beaker containing a liquid, why does the liquid level in the tube rise? Also, if it rises, won't there be a difference in the pressure at points A and B?( A is inside the tube and B is outside the tube but both are at the same level)

Comment: Could you supply a picture or a link to a picture that shows the setup?

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/DCnEzbCHJAXCzutx6 is the image for reference

Comment: Your first question is addressed expansively, clearly, and unambiguously in discussions that are given behind the link that you provide as well as in other internet links (search "capillary action"). The answer to the second question is: No, the pressures at the two points (inside and out) are the same, as the fundamental derivations behind the link you provide also show. What else remains to explain here?

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/517252/243267) will answer your question.